# C++ pre-determining the length of a VARCHAR using ODBC bound parameters

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, odbc

I have been playing with Row-Wise, Column-Wise and parameter binding to try to find a way to point to a non sequential array of buffers for a VARCHAR column return.

The return could have 10 chars or 8000. I do not want to allocate 8000 x nRows bytes of memory obviously so I have been playing with ways to to this better.

The first obvious way is to allocate a buffer 8000 bytes long and then once SqlFetchO() has returned the column length, allocate the correct size for the return and *copy* it over. Since copy is expensive, I am trying to avoid this.

The next idea I had was to issue two SELECT statements. The first would be:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(Description) from SpecialOffer WHERE MinQty > 0
```

I am not sure how expensive this is, but assuming that no data is actually copied from the database, and the 2 byte length field is just read, this could be fast? Before executing the second query I can allocate an array with each member having the exact length.

Is there any way to get the exact VARCHAR Column length information before the row is retrieved in SQL Server?

Also, is there any way to use specify an pointer to the buffer pointer (ie double de-referencing required by ODBC driver). This would allow me to use Row-Wise binding and an array of pointers to the buffers for example (using the second technique).

Answer (score 1):

If you SQLPrepare the query, you can then call SQLNumResultCols to find the number of columns, then SQLDescribeCol to get the length and data types of each column, and then use this information to allocate and bind the data buffers. Then use SQLExecute and SQLFetch to return the data into those buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Necro answer here, but the existing one doesn't really address your question.  No, there's no way to get the actual length of a given column in a given row length before the row is retrieved by the driver.

You either need to allocate more memory than you need (which may or may not be acceptable, depending on the query and the application) or you need to use your `DATALENGTH` trick.  If you do choose to go that route, you'll need to ensure that your second query exactly matches the first -- an `ORDER BY` clause on your primary key is probably required to *ensure* that SQL Server doesn't jack with the ordering of the columns you get back between the first and second queries.

In addition, you might want to look at running both queries in the same ODBC `Execute` call.  That will minimize roundtrips to the database and might buy you a bit of extra performance.