# Fetching Large data from Sql Server using ODBC - varchar, varbinary

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc, large-data

How can i read varchar from sql server using native C++ code. Do you have any advice? What is the best way to do it?

My application(native c++) allows users to write Sql queries external and use that file to fetch some data from database which can be used inside our application.
Now the problem is customers can write queries which includes both small(int for example) and large data type(For Ex varchar and varbinary) columns ordered randomly.

I am using SQLBindCol to bind to application variables.I cannot use this method to bind large data types unless I allocate the buffer large enough to store the data(Length unknown while Binding). Data can be of any size(less than max size allowed by sql server column), I have memory concerns in allocating large buffers. So I thought I can use SQLGetData, but i see the below from microsoft.

> The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver does not support using SQLGetData to retrieve data in random column order. All unbound columns processed with SQLGetData must have higher column ordinals than the bound columns in the result set. 
>   [sqlgetdata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-api/sqlgetdata?view=sql-server-2017)

And also from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.data.odbc/Mg_5rD4jrgg/sv5kV0oe358J) it is said

> For generic application, you may use SQLFetch + SQLGetData to obtain the maximum length and data. Actually, for a very long column (image datatype), 
>   it is recommended to use SQLGetData since you can get the data in chunk, instead of pre-allocating a large buffer. However, if the amount of data is 
>   not so large, you may use the datatype "varbinary(2048)

I can reorder the select columns in the query and use both sqlcolBind and sqlgetdata. But i am not very much convinced to do this.

From this stack overflow link [pre-determining-the-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412864/c-pre-determining-the-length-of-a-varchar-using-odbc-bound-parameters)
It is suggested to either  allocate more memory than you need or I had to issue two SELECT statements, one is query having larger datatype and other query to get the actual size of column using DATALENGTH, something like

```
select name, description from users where username = 'johnce'
select DATALENGTH(description) from description where username = 'johnce'
```

I am very much confused with all these information. I could find any example showing my scenario. Could someone advice which is the best approach in my scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to this? I am also facing same issue. please let me know.

Comment: Yes I found the solution myself. But forgot to post the answer. Now I do not remember much details, but I will try to explain what I did/remeber on highlevel.

I used SQLBindCol for all columns except for the columns which are long field type.

For long field type columns, I first used SQLGetData to get the length of the data(last paramter of SQLGetData).
and now I again called SQLGetData but this time with the allocated buffer(which is char*) of length we got in the previous step.
And finally we can retrieve the data from the buffer by casting to the required type.
Hope this helps.

Comment: did this solved the problem even when such columns are not the last columns in the statements?

Comment: Yes. It did solve.